# How to secure or encrypt WFS service in GeoServer?

Tags: security, openlayers, geoserver, wfs

I am trying to display some layers on the webpage using the OpenLayers library from the WFS service from the GeoServer. It contains all the parameters available with the layer, which is very insecure. I want some plugin or anything that can help me to encrypt some important data, which can be decrypted at the client level without disturbing the actual output of the layer.

Also, help me with the alternative way of achieving this, if there is nothing available to encrypt the data, there could be another way to secure data using the WFS service. Or suggest some other libraries for displaying encrypted data layers.

Comment: what have you tried so far? https, authentication, views that hide data, geofence plugin?

Comment: I haven't tried anything till now as I was using the WMS service. But now I want to improve the way maps were presented by hovering and clicking events on boundaries, so I need to use the WFS service.